# "sendto" from multiple threads for a single socket

Tags: linux, networking, udp, low-latency

I have an application which runs a UDP server that sends quite some data to its clients (few hundreds). It does not send non-stop data, but only every few ms (e.g. 50ms). The point is: When data is sent, it must be fast. Unfortunately, the call to `sendto` or `sendmsg` can get really slow.

A possible solution was then to call these functions on multiple threads for the same server socket, but different clients.

Unfortunately, the performance increase is by far not as big as expected (e.g. for n threads the time needed is by far not divided by n). Might there be some issue if `sendto` / `sendmsg` is called for the same server socket from multiple threads? Can this be avoided?

(buffers and kernel parameters are already tuned, so that should not be an issue)

Thank you very much

Comment: It got slow because you filled the socket send buffer. Adding threads cannot possibly solve that. Increase the buffer, reduce the datagram size, reduce the send rate, or reduce your expectations.

Comment: Any issue about performance begs for measurements.

Answer (score -1):

You can try sending the datagram using raw socket, you will have to create the UDP header manually, but you will bypass the UDP stack handling, this might solve the delay you are experiencing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).